# global optin available to set all numbers in script as decimal?

Tags: bash

I just discovered the problem doing arithmetic using vars with leading 0's. I found the solution for setting individual vars to decimal using:

```
N=016
N=$((10#$N)) # force decimal (base 10)
echo $((N + 2))
# result is 18, ok
```

But I have multiple vars in my script that may or may not take a leading zero when run. I wonder if there is a global option that can be set to specify that all numbers in the script are to be interpreted as decimal? Or would there be a potential problem with doing so that I perhaps did not take into account?

I thought the `set` command might have such an option but after referring to the man page I did not read anything that looked like it would do the job.

Comment: If all your initializations are of the form `VAR=0xxx`, you could just use `sed` to strip the leading zeros: `s/=0*/=/g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is an (unfortunate) convention established by the B language than a leading `0` introduces an octal number.

By looking at the `bash` sources, it seems that this convention is hard-coded in several places (`lib/sh/strtol.c`, `builtins/common.c` and concerning that specific case in `expr.c`, function `strlong`). **So to answer to your question, no there isn't a *global* option to set all numbers as decimal**.

If you have number in base 10 potentially prefixed by `0` you want perform calculation on, you might use the `${N#0}` notation to refer to them.

```
sh$ N=010
sh$ echo $((${N#0}+0))
10
```

I don't know if this is more *readable*, or even less *error prone_* than the solution you proposed in your question, though.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to OP's question. He wanted a solution that does not require him to change each `VAR` in his script to that.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu _"He wanted a solution that does not require him to change each VAR in his script to that"_ As I said, by looking at the bash sources, such option does not exist. Either the OP has to live with that -- or somehow pre-process its script (as it has been suggested in a comment).

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a reference to the one function responsible for the string to long conversion while `bash` evaluates an arithmetic expression. The convention _"prefix 0 for octal"_  is hard-coded there too.

Comment: so if there's no global option, it seems best then to specify the var as decimal at the time it is set so that there is no need to specify it as decimal or strip its leading zero each time it may be called later in the script. Do you think, or no?

Comment: @nanker Without seeing your script, it is hard to have a definite answer concerning your specific case. Nevertheless, in the general case, I would go for converting/stripping as soon as possible. Preferably just after reading the value.